# How to convert Date to format "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss-hh:mm"?

Tags: apex, date

I want to convert Date from "YYYY-MM-DD" to "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss-hh:mm" format in Apex. 
Ex. "2016-05-20" should be converted to "2016-05-20T00:00:00-00:00".
Any help/suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried "**yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX**" pattern and I am able to convert Date from "YYYY-MM-DD" to "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss-hh:mm" format as given below-

```
Date d = System.today();
Datetime myDT = datetime.newInstance(d.year(), d.month(),d.day());
String myDate = myDT.format('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX');
```

"YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss-hh:mm" is ISO 8601 format.
Check this link- [https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#isoformats](http://ISO-formats) for ISO formats.

Refer [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html](http://Date-format-patterns) for formatting and parsing dates.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Datetime dt = datetime.newInstance(dToday.year(), dToday.month(),dToday.day());
```

here `dToday` is your field.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it is converting to "2016-05-20T08:46:52.372Z" format.

Comment: so you want o add `-hh:mm` in the end again.